# Compress the json data response

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there any way to compress the JSON data response? Actually, I created one API but the JSON data which we're sending through the API is very big. So It increases the response time.

Can we reduce its size by compressing mechanism in nodeJS?

Comment: You can send chunks if possible

Comment: https://github.com/sapienlab/jsonpack

Answer (score 1):

If you have a human readable JSON structure, you can tell node to remove all unnecessary whitespace. `JSON.stringify()` already does that by default.

If you want to use compression to reduce the amout of data transferred over the wire, there is the [compression](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression) middleware available, which supports `gzip` and `deflate`

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on GRPC. GRPC internally use protobuff I.e. a compression technique open source by Google or if you don't want to use GRPC then you can use protobuff only